# Giving links in Menu based on some condition

Tags: php, yii

I have a situation here. In my project the menu section contains some anchor tags, it will work perfectly when we in index page, but moving to other pages i want to give the real links there, so my question is how to check which page is viewing or how to check the the site viewer is not in index page

```
<li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>
```

I want to change `href` conditionally, for example when I'm in index the above `href` attribute is OK, and when I'm in another page, for example register, then the `href` attribute change to `index.php/site/index#home`

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :**
thank you [uttara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811838/1343222),I found a solution with the help of her

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$page = pathinfo($url);
$filename = $page['filename'];
$href = ($filename=='root_directory' || $filename=='index'  || $filename=='site')?'':Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
?>
<a href="<?php echo $href ; ?>#home" class="active">Home</a>
```

Comment: Why don't you always use index.php/site/index#home ?

Comment: @nischayn22, we can use it always, but it skips some animations ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$page = pathinfo($url);
$filename = $page['filename'];
```

`$filename` will give you the name of current page being viewed

and you can check for

```
if($filename != 'index')
{
    echo '<li><a href="index.php/site/index#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>';
}
else
{
    echo '<li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>';
}
```

remember `$filename` gives you just the filename without extension

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu) widget, and this takes care of the highlights, appearance, etc. Plus you can use custom CSS afterwards.

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=> 'YOUR_URL#home'),
            array('label'=>'About Us', 'url'=>'YOUR_URL#about_us)'
        )
       ); 
?>
```

Comment: By default, the active item is appended the 'active' css class, but you can also change it using the option of the CMenu called 'activeCssClass', and put your name.

Comment: this is ok, but i have some issues while using the widget,i knew this thing. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

first give the id to anchor tag and then put condition like below

```
  <?php 
// the php code
   $flag=strpos('index.php',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
   {
  ?>
   <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
                       $("#idofanchortg").attr('href','hrefyou want to add');
           });

   </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CMenu widget provided by Yii 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/211/creating-a-css-driven-drop-down-menu-using-cmenu/

Answer (score 0):

First of all I prefer to leave responsibility in just one place.

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getHomeHrefLink(); ?>" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about_us">About Us</a></li>
```

I prefer this way 'couse code is more clean. Well. Now we know that all our controllers extends Controller class (/protected/components/Controller.php). In this place we can add

```
public function getHomeHrefLink() {
    // when I'm in index page the href attribute is #home
    // when I'm in register page the href attribute is index.php/site/index#home
}
```

So come on: We can you $this->action (for controller name) and $this->action->id (for action name) to understand where we are:

```
public function getHomeHrefLink() {
    return $this->createUrl('index/site', array());


    // when I'm in register page the href attribute is index.php/site/index#home
    return '#home;
}
```